# Nasty integrals involving polylogarithms

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, special-functions

Is there a general method how to solve integrals including polylogarithms? I have, for example, a following peculiar integral:

$$\int_0^1 \frac{\log (1-q)}{(1-q)^{19}} \big[19122427017242392409179196696957 -2335312823676226739258108857200 \pi ^2-290355604888434431371406862640901 q+32737624286330384009900385643800 \pi ^2
   q+2089178147864338015378359942349146 q^2-217908181258375090989657061033200 \pi ^2 q^2-9513735107311961105716228372823832 q^3+923058652929127659169477549327800 \pi ^2
   q^3+30860609840601979343569796243664360 q^4-2809234642150007839007261169271200 \pi ^2 q^4-75991613070307679674084684299763488 q^5+6560138082212689647470512926380400 \pi ^2
   q^5+147604422934589574241111368769031514 q^6-12225064353406525792601847884728800 \pi ^2 q^6-231661749521735051694587401454488374 q^7+18614430483751971866343908315754000 \pi
   ^2 q^7+298158588677298781555571530676473698 q^8-23467372646806215931232745831715200 \pi ^2 q^8-317258462849638359532191702700757050 q^9+24645135112158586773581379231285600
   \pi ^2 q^9+279929745859987197112521991075600990 q^{10}-21578983058687084626530891022466400 \pi ^2 q^{10}-204525346750399538308156387121441190
   q^{11}+15702582554471282285512462526560800 \pi ^2 q^{11}+123049277403587430345156505609140720 q^{12}-9430354354307541344225967691260000 \pi ^2
   q^{12}-60342329966544036497302398449157240 q^{13}+4622406501952432638430248014413200 \pi ^2 q^{13}+23738252991464115594141538592264430
   q^{14}-1818869679546039116051640669453600 \pi ^2 q^{14}-7312550577333389628853566957018834 q^{15}+560636064795229527948416643193200 \pi ^2
   q^{15}+1699354671638585927650255051925577 q^{16}-130382484017845412425019267350800 \pi ^2 q^{16}-280173803150789489806907495704617 q^{17}+21513060264068052978453696664200 \pi
   ^2 q^{17}+29212691355365195449956724538624 q^{18}-2244803977761215443782290650800 \pi ^2 q^{18}-1448394095369360889798167890490 q^{19}+111380159353759803311707564200 \pi ^2
   q^{19}-864839351159251344060440256000 \pi ^2 \log (q)+9614284037777341680385275648000 \pi ^2 q \log (q)-48596947298066064189458694528000 \pi ^2 q^2 \log
   (q)+149016194597643828944407014096000 \pi ^2 q^3 \log (q)-311515153604740784777334800544000 \pi ^2 q^4 \log (q)+472522854921446523354235979904000 \pi ^2 q^5 \log
   (q)-540131604846004142202578675328000 \pi ^2 q^6 \log (q)+476835369490723415021630300520000 \pi ^2 q^7 \log (q)-330431763957397218290451028752000 \pi ^2 q^8 \log
   (q)+181570501304738210584142319096000 \pi ^2 q^9 \log (q)-79469952891751512800087794416000 \pi ^2 q^{10} \log (q)+27618312749376667202083351152000 \pi ^2 q^{11} \log
   (q)-7469792604527284717674468480000 \pi ^2 q^{12} \log (q)+1441811254291252370952714288000 \pi ^2 q^{13} \log (q)-47548846798971176802583440000 \pi ^2 q^{14} \log
   (q)-242992965510346357364274216000 \pi ^2 q^{15} \log (q)+315652971889245500921659248000 \pi ^2 q^{16} \log (q)-286658885174869914970791528000 \pi ^2 q^{17} \log
   (q)+190547414679020492013416496000 \pi ^2 q^{18} \log (q)-91723410310948362363008592000 \pi ^2 q^{19} \log (q)+31251841079492830435486848000 \pi ^2 q^{20} \log
   (q)-7178196236973842421012672000 \pi ^2 q^{21} \log (q)+1000683546793492378825008000 \pi ^2 q^{22} \log (q)-64152027504348590478672000 \pi ^2 q^{23} \log (q)+116396280 \log
   (1-q) \left((-1+q)^2 \left(-257586022317616038442244+3541119036337161972270259 q-22985344007557567401249245 q^2+94080232161007231115696965 q^3-272947169011867587813604265
   q^4+596855442237497586986976649 q^5-1019309093239565006695750169 q^6+1388155171326881304329317345 q^7-1524633136813377308169137885 q^8+1356305480530438789865344115
   q^9-975804898738457785419837691 q^{10}+563741882769447393607104851 q^{11}-257984481217331023678963375 q^{12}+91454555996476460965835495 q^{13}-24229819048292743306257775
   q^{14}+4517255786475215854979111 q^{15}-528777243429852450045991 q^{16}+29245925849336575939850 q^{17}\right)+17463600 \left(2552782515875592-28378884658059936
   q+143445643657566096 q^2-439857339564018222 q^3+919512319237712508 q^4-1394765491161108528 q^5+1594329068484771696 q^6-1407494920941509015 q^7+975349269884284614
   q^8-535949249427887597 q^9+234574786644003962 q^{10}-81522129873123914 q^{11}+22048899523933360 q^{12}-4255854634983666 q^{13}+140351921539830 q^{14}+717252508230687
   q^{15}-931726090681386 q^{16}+846143031204471 q^{17}-562446780417522 q^{18}+270743829850494 q^{19}-92247367548336 q^{20}+21188182319304 q^{21}-2953759514706
   q^{22}+189360225054 q^{23}\right) \log ^2(q)\right)+2032698075408000 \left(2552782515875592-28378884658059936 q+143445643657566096 q^2-439857339564018222
   q^3+919512319237712508 q^4-1394765491161108528 q^5+1594329068484771696 q^6-1407494920941509015 q^7+975349269884284614 q^8-535949249427887597 q^9+234574786644003962
   q^{10}-81522129873123914 q^{11}+22048899523933360 q^{12}-4255854634983666 q^{13}+140351921539830 q^{14}+717252508230687 q^{15}-931726090681386 q^{16}+846143031204471
   q^{17}-562446780417522 q^{18}+270743829850494 q^{19}-92247367548336 q^{20}+21188182319304 q^{21}-2953759514706 q^{22}+189360225054 q^{23}\right) \log (q) \text{Li}_2(1-q)\big] \mathrm dq$$

Comment: In fact, I have a collection of in total 15 very similar integrals, 8 of which i was able to solve using plenty of tricks in Mathematica. The result should be, according to previous results, an expression involving zeta at integer values.

Comment: P.s. I retracted my vote because MAYBE we can see what happens when written in a clearer way

Comment: Someone please post an answer with a complete *unabbreviated* deduction. (Joking.)

Comment: This might be a textbook example of how to make your question as UNATTRACTIVE AS POSSIBLE to anybody who might be interested in writing an answer. The only way that expression could be more tedious to parse would be if you'd written those integer coefficients using Roman numerals. (Don't get any ideas!)

Answer (score 3):

This is just a comment, but too long to be written in the comments section.

As I like to proceed when meeting those nasty things, I would suggest you to use Dirac's Elegance.

What I mean is that the integrand function is full of large numbers and patterns which could be written in a shorter way. For example, if you just name $a_0, \ldots, a_{19}$ the first terms and $b_0, \ldots, b_{23}$ the next terms, the **first two parts** of the integrand function can be written as

$$a_0 + a_1q + a_2q^2 + \ldots + a_{19}q^{19} = \sum_{k = 0}^{19} a_kq^k$$

$$b_0\log(q) + b_1q \log(q) + \ldots + b_{23}q^{23}\log(q) = \log(q)\sum_{k = 0}^{23} b_kq^k$$

The other parts I leave them to you to be written in a compact elegant way.

When you will have finished, please rewrite the whole question by making use of this form so we could go on by investigating the eventual absolute convergence and split into $N$ parts the integrand and make try to get out of this tunnel!

Answer (score 1):

$$7000862380461139672573968144870 \zeta
   (3)-\frac{25106433798599975547209462384350566086427971}{3127445521200}-\frac{15277122989236784320739564512904737 \pi
   ^2}{58344}+36405909335514889429116587730 \pi ^4$$

should be the answer